# MySQL select where column is not empty

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySQL, can I select columns only where something exists?

For example, I have the following query:

```
select phone, phone2
from jewishyellow.users
where phone like '813%'
and phone2
```

I'm trying to select only the rows where phone starts with 813 and phone2 has something in it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "`phone2` has something in it?"  People are taking guesses as to whether you mean `phone2` IS NOT NULL, is not blank, is not exclusively whitespace, etc.

Comment: if "something" exists, it obviously is not null.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Compare value of `phone2` with empty string:

```
select phone, phone2 
from jewishyellow.users 
where phone like '813%' and phone2<>''
```

Note that `NULL` value is interpreted as `false`.

Comment: Single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: `phone2<>""` will not make it past any SQL syntax checker.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: But it works in mysql. This is the only checker that's matter

Comment: @ivan: News to me, sorry about that.

Comment: <> is same as != . it was simple. but I didn't know :)

Comment: @OMGPonies Ponies What's the difference between double and simple quotes? Aren't they both exactly the same and just denote an empty string? I don't see why they wouldn't pass a syntax checker

Answer (score 53):

To check if field is NULL use `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL` operators.

MySql reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: OP is asking about only rows that have something in the phone2 field. IS NOT NULL returns everything that literally is not set to NULL, even the empty string "". !='', or <>'' as Ivan said in the accepted answer, will not return empty strings or NULL values. In other words IS NOT NULL is a subset of !='', but they are not equivalent.

Comment: NULL is not empty.

Answer (score 46):

**UPDATE 2024, MySQL 8** - welp, I guess this behavior changed for some reason and it doesn't actually work anymore.

```sql
SELECT if(NULL > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if('' > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if(' ' > '','true','false');-- true
SELECT if('\n' > '','true','false');-- true
SELECT if('\t' > '','true','false');-- true
SELECT if('Yeet' > '','true','false');-- true
```

---

An answer that I've been using that has been working for me quite well that I didn't already see here (this question is very old, so it may have not worked then) is actually

```
SELECT t.phone, 
       t.phone2 
  FROM jewishyellow.users t
 WHERE t.phone LIKE '813%' 
   AND t.phone2 > ''
```

Notice the `> ''` part, which will check if the value is not null, and if the value isn't just whitespace or blank.

Basically, if the field has something in it other than whitespace or `NULL`, it is true. It's also super short, so it's easy to write, and another plus over the `COALESCE()` and `IFNULL()` functions is that this is index friendly, since you're not comparing the output of a function on a field to anything.

Test cases:

```
SELECT if(NULL > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if('' > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if(' ' > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if('\n' > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if('\t' > '','true','false');-- false
SELECT if('Yeet' > '','true','false');-- true
```

---

**UPDATE** There is a caveat to this that I didn't expect, but numerical values that are zero or below are *not* greater than a blank string, so **if you're dealing with numbers that can be zero or negative then DO NOT DO THIS**, it bit me very recently and was very difficult to debug :(

If you're using strings (char, varchar, text, etc.), then this will be perfectly be fine, just be careful with numerics.

Comment: This is impressive. Short, no need for function calls, and gets the job done. Thank you.

Comment: Quick side question: is there a similar tip for the opposite condition, i.e. if I need to select something which is empty or `NULL`? Currently I'm using both `= ''` and `IS NULL` at once

Comment: @aexl sadly not as easily, doing `not null>''` returns `null` which is still `false` from the perspective of limiting rows

Comment: I'd recommend NOT using this with mariadb.  It's a lot slower than the other choices. Or, at least compare performance if it matters to you.

Answer (score 45):

Check for `NULL` and empty string values:

```
select phone
, phone2 
from users 
where phone like '813%' 
and trim(coalesce(phone2, '')) <>''
```

N.B. I think COALESCE() is SQL standard(-ish), whereas ISNULL() is not.

Comment: You don't need to use the trim function, since in MySQL a string of any number of spaces is equal to another string of any number of spaces, I've written in answer on this in quite some detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/42723975/728236

Answer (score 21):

If there are spaces in the phone2 field from inadvertant data entry, you can ignore those records with the IFNULL and TRIM functions:

```
SELECT phone, phone2
FROM jewishyellow.users
WHERE phone LIKE '813%'
    AND TRIM(IFNULL(phone2,'')) <> '';
```

Comment: You don't need to use the trim function, since in MySQL a string of any number of spaces is equal to another string of any number of spaces, I've written in answer on this in quite some detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/42723975/728236

Answer (score 8):

Surprisingly(as nobody else mentioned it before) found that the condition below does the job:

```
WHERE ORD(field_to_check) > 0
```

when we need to exclude both null and empty values.
Is anybody aware of downsides of the approach?

Comment: ive been trying for hours to get the syntax correct and this just solved everything thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
select phone, phone2 from jewishyellow.users 
where phone like '813%' and phone2 is not null
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a `NULL` value and an empty string `''` which **is** a value. If you want to check against an empty string, use `column <> ''` as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT phone, phone2 
FROM jewishyellow.users 
WHERE phone like '813%' and (phone2 <> "");
```

May need some tweakage depending on what your default value is. If you allowed Null fill, then you can do "Not NULL" instead, which is obviously better.

Comment: I won't mark you down but: 1) There is no `NOT()` function in MySQL 2) `phone2=""` will not make it past any SQL syntax checker.

Comment: Heh, sorry. I use a lot of different SQL servers.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to look specifically at the [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) of the column values. (not to be confused with `LENGTH`)

Using a criteria where the character length is greater than 0, will avoid false positives when the column values can be falsey, such as in the event of an integer column with a value of `0` or `NULL`. Behaving more consistently across varying data-types.

Which results in any value that is at least 1 character long, or otherwise not empty.

### *Example* https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQvEhY1SH6wfruAvnmWdj5/1

```
SELECT phone, phone2
FROM users
WHERE phone LIKE '813%'
AND CHAR_LENGTH(phone2) > 0
```

*Table Data*

```
users
phone (varchar 12) | phone2 (int 10)
"813-123-4567"     | NULL
"813-123-4567"     | 1
"813-123-4567"     | 0

users2
phone (varchar 12) | phone2 (varchar 12)
"813-123-4567"     | NULL
"813-123-4567"     | "1"
"813-123-4567"     | "0"
"813-123-4567"     | ""
```

***`CHAR_LENGTH(phone2) > 0` Results* (same)**

```
users
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0

users2
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0
```

---

**Alternatives**

*`phone2 <> ''` Results* (different)

```
users
813-123-4567       | 1

users2
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0
```

*`phone2 > ''` Results*  (different)

```
users
813-123-4567       | 1

users2
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0
```

*`COALESCE(phone2, '') <> ''` Results* (same)

*Note: the results differ from `phone2 IS NOT NULL AND phone2 <> ''` which is not expected*

```
users
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0

users2
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0
```

*`phone2 IS NOT NULL AND phone2 <> ''` Results* (different)

```
users
813-123-4567       | 1

users2
813-123-4567       | 1
813-123-4567       | 0
```

Comment: I find this is the most intuitive syntax

Answer (score 2):

We can use CASE for setting blank value to some char or String.
I am using NA as Default string.

```
SELECT phone,   
CASE WHEN phone2 = '' THEN 'NA' END AS phone2 ELSE ISNULL(phone2,0) 
FROM jewishyellow.users  WHERE phone LIKE '813%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT t.phone, 
       t.phone2 
  FROM jewishyellow.users t
 WHERE t.phone LIKE '813%' 
   AND t.phone2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I noticed that sometimes `IS NOT NULL` is not applied to string only columns with empty values (`''`). I don't know why, but just wanted to point it out. It is wiser to use `t.phone2 <> ''` when checking for empty string columns.

Comment: @Dzhuneyt Cause NULL is not the same as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like operator wildcard to achieve this:

```
SELECT t.phone, 
       t.phone2 
FROM jewishyellow.users t
WHERE t.phone LIKE '813%' 
  AND t.phone2 like '[0-9]';
```

in this way, you could get all phone2 that have a number prefix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a varchar column, both the methods of `IS NOT NULL` & `!= ''` **didn't work**, but the following worked for me. Just putting this out here.

```
SELECT * FROM `db_name` WHERE `column_name` LIKE '%*%'
```