# SQL/MySQL NOT NULL vs NOT EMPTY

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I'd like to limit my query to show only rows where a certain field is not empty. I found [this thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?571768-SELECTING-field-is-not-empty-using-mysql) where someone posed the same question and was told to use `IS NOT NULL`. I tried that, but I'm still getting rows where the field is empty.

What is the correct way to do this? Is Null the same thing as Empty in SQL/MySQL?

My query, if you're interested is:
`SELECT * FROM records WHERE (party_zip='49080' OR party_zip='49078' OR party_zip='49284' ) AND partyfn IS NOT NULL`

Comment: can you post some sample data

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post actual data from my tables as it contains sensitive info. You can write some with just the 2 rows easily though if you'd like to test.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869264/mysql-select-where-column-not-empty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When comparing a `NULL` value, the result in most cases becomes `NULL` and therefor haves the same result as `0` (the FALSE value in MySQL) inside `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

In your given example, you don't need to include `IS NOT NULL`. Instead simply use `party_zip IN ('49080', '49078', '49284')`. `NULL` can't be 49080, 49078, 49284 or any other number or string.

What you do need to think about though, is when checking for empty values. `!party_zip` won't return `TRUE`/`1` if the value is `NULL`. Instead use `OR columns IS NULL` or `!COALESCE(party_zip, 0)`

Answer (score 40):

I got it by using `AND (partyfn IS NOT NULL AND partyfn != '')`