# Display only the columns that contains data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that have 35 columns and some of those columns are empty and I've already made the page and the query to retrieve the data from the data base but the problem is All the data including the empty ones, and I want to know if there is a resolving to these problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the where clause in the query

like

```
 Select * from TableName where FieldName is Not Null And Field2 is not null
```

Similarly you can add as many filters as you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE somefield IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query (assuming you're using SQL) should have something like

```
... my_table.my_field IS NOT NULL ...
```

see also: [MySQL select where column is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869264/mysql-select-where-column-not-empty)