# how to retrieve values from database that are not null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve values from my table that are not null. Below is the picture of my table forumposts.

[image: forumposts table]

I want to retrieve all the thread titles that are not null. I'm using the following code :

```
$forum_activities = "";
$sql = "SELECT thread_title FROM forumposts WHERE thread_title IS NOT NULL";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $thread_titles = $row["thread_title"];
        $forum_activities .= "<a href='viewthread.php'>$thread_titles</a><hr />";
    }
}
```

Null values are still coming. Please help!!

Comment: what is your thread_title TYPE ?

Comment: It should be `thread_title IS NOT NULL AND thread_title<>''`

Comment: NULL is not the same as 'blank' or 'empty' or 'space'. GIGO

Comment: my thread_title type is varchar(255).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869264/mysql-select-where-column-is-not-empty

Comment: @Gopal1216 yeah but is it varchar(255) not null? in which case the column won't contain null values

Comment: You need to learn how to make table structures to get correct data before writing DDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change it into:

```
$sql = "SELECT thread_title FROM forumposts WHERE thread_title != ''";
```

Which will select anything that is different than an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `thread_title` is

```
varchar(255) and Default value is NULL
```

and USe your query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forumposts` (
  `thread_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `forumposts` (`thread_title`) VALUES
('foo'),
('bar'),
(NULL);

SELECT thread_title FROM forumposts WHERE thread_title IS NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
THREAD_TITLE

foo
bar
```

[**HERE IS THE WORKING SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80c6c/1)

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT thread_title FROM forumposts WHERE thread_title"; //Remove the IS NOT NULL
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $thread_titles = $row["thread_title"];
        $forum_activities .= "<a href='viewthread.php'>$thread_titles</a><hr />";
    }
}
```