# Output the column name with an entry that contains null (SQL, eloquent)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I got the following database: (mysql)

```
columns: A    B    C
row:     1   null  3
```

I want to have a list of the columns with an entry that is not null.
This is what the list should look like:

```
A (1)
C (3)
```

In order to achieve this I want to get an array of columns, with their values. Like this:

```
{{column => 'a', value => 1}, {column => 'c', value => 3}}
```

So I can loop through them to create the list.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to retrieve values from database that are not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591333/how-to-retrieve-values-from-database-that-are-not-null)

Comment: The specified duplicate seemed to have nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many databases, you can use `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when a is null then 'a' end),
                 (case when b is null then 'b' end),
                 (case when c is null then 'c' end)
                ) as null_columns
```

Comment: Thank You so much!!!!!, It works now!!! I had to run that as a raw query(using laravel) And then explode that, got a list now, thx!

Answer (score 0):

This might achieve what you are looking for :

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(
          "{", 
          CONCAT_WS(
               ",",
               CONCAT("{column => 'a', value => ", a, "}"),
               CONCAT("{column => 'b', value => ", b, "}"),
               CONCAT("{column => 'c', value => ", c, "}")
          ),
          "}"
     ) AS myArray 
FROM myTable
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83b1ac5b8150ebf600ca269166e8cf46)