# Date matching loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a time registry for employes. I have two columns. `Stamp_in` and `Stamp_Out`. When an employe register in, a `DateTime` value is stored in db. Looking like: `$datetime_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and equal when register out. But when registering in, the value in `stamp_out` column will be: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. And the same for registering out, in `stamp_in` column.

Now, when i loop this out, i like to match dates on same day to print on the same row, but i don't want the "empty" dates to print.

How should this code look like?

This is what i got so far:

**PHP**

```
//Loop out the result
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_in']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_in']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

**I tried**

```
if($row['usr_stamp_in'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"{
  while($row ...
```

Comment: instead of dealing with php when your employee registers in, why don't you just act it in your db with a timestamp like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NOW() on login/logout ? You're almost on it with your query, but you need to do it this way : while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ if($row['usr_stamp_in']!="0000-00-00 00:00:00"){//do whatever you want}}. BTW to match same day, you need to fix it with a WHERE and then ORDER BY when you get data from your db AND you should remove empty rows from db in your query too with a WHERE clause ;)

Comment: Think you should think about your database layout.

Comment: @Jens. Yes, you're logging events. Only one date is needed, and a field indicating the type of event.

Comment: I'm on a webhost company, wich server time isn't the same as mine. So, timestamp will give the wrong time. Otherwise very useful tips. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the if statement inside your while loop:

```
//Loop out the result
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row['usr_stamp_in'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_in']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_in']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

You could also do it in mysql as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE usr_tstamp_in != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY usr_tstamp_in DESC;
```

This will select all records from the 'users' table that do not have a usr_tstamp_in with value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and orders those records by date newest to oldest.

I still suggest you use the PHP part as well. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing the filter part in your SQL query using the not equal operator `<>`.
Things will look like `SELECT * FROM employee_table WHERE usr_stamp_in <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

To be more precise there is a topic on SO about that [MySQL select where column is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869264/mysql-select-where-column-is-not-empty)

Comment: I'd go for != to check whether usr_stamp_in is set. But good suggestion!