# NOT IN is not working in MYSql. and Not Exists not giving proper result

Tags: mysql, not-exists, notin

1. Trying to fetch record which does not have NULL or '' string using not in() function but not working. Please give any suggestion.

   ```
    select * 
    from table 
    where colm1 = 'xyz' 
      and colm2 not in (NULL, '') 
      and id = 268594;
   ```
2. In second scenario, I have table A and B. Table B can have multiple records mapped to one table A record. I want to perform where clause on table B. If record is available then need to check value is not null or empty. How can I perform without performing select query 2 times:

Table A:

| a_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "xyz" |

Table B:

| B_id | type | value | A_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "x" | "abd" | 1 |
| 2 | "y" | "cdv" | 1 |

So want to select record of table A if record does not exists in Table B with type as "x and A_id" =1 and if exists then select table A record only if value is NULL or '' .

I tried these queries but they are not working:

```
select * 
from A 
where not exists (select * 
                  from B 
                  where type = 'x' 
                    and value = null 
                     or value = '' 
                    and A_id = a_id);
```

Comment: How many questions are there?

Comment: two questions are there. I mentioned as 1 and 2.

Comment: It is easier to divide them in 2 questions

Comment: Yup. One question per post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * 
 from table 
 where colm1 = 'xyz' 
   and colm2 not in (NULL, '') 
   and id = 268594;
```

[Try using `IS NOT NULL` and `<> ''`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869264/mysql-select-where-column-is-not-empty/42723975), e.g.:

```
 select * 
 from table 
 where colm1 = 'xyz' 
   and colm2 IS NOT NULL AND colm2<>''
   and id = 268594;
```

Comment: it is returing record even i have value as ''. 
colm2 IS NOT NULL AND colm2<>'' this line will not work bz colm2 can't have both value at same time.

Comment: Well, what _is_ the colm2 value? A space? A non-printing character?

Comment: colm2 have "abc" varchar type

Comment: Let me try again. You say the query is "not working". I interpret "not working" to mean "the query returns results where colm2 is null or empty". I'm asking whether colm2 is _actually_ null or empty, or does it just _appear_ to be null or empty - i.e. is there actually a space or non-printing character.

Comment: it is empty, you can say empty string like ''.